# Gimpfu paste from windows clipboard

Tags: python, gimpfu

Trying to paste the windows clipboard into a new image in gimp 2, I tried:

```
image = pdb.gimp_edit_paste_as_new()
display = pdb.gimp_display_new(image)
```

Line 2 gives error:

> Procedure 'gimp-display-new' has been called with an invalid ID for
> argument 'image'.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting images from system clipboard does not seem currently (Gimp 2.1) to be supported, only from the Gimp internal clipboard.